# How to change The browser URL addresse when click on picture like instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If we have some pictures shown on the page as thumbnails, and when the user click on the picture , the page show the full picture using any JavaScript or JQuery methods.

how we can change the browser url address to point to picture instead of the main page website while keeping the user on the current page.

for example:

if we visit any instagram account for example

http://instagram.com/fofo

and when we click on any photo the script will change the address url in the browser to

http://instagram.com/p/ReTycBy2Bj/

for example

how we can do something that?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a script that will solve my question

After review +lshearer answer and start searching about "pushState" and while im searching I found this url http://html5.gingerhost.com/seattle which helps me to understand how to change the URL of browser address bar without loading it's content.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>some title</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var original_url = window.location.pathname;
    $("#show").click(function() {
    href = "picurlhere.jpg";
    // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
    history.pushState('sss', 'New URL: '+href, href);   
});

$("#close").click(function() {
   // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
   history.pushState('sss', 'New URL: '+original_url, original_url);   
});
});
</script>
<body>
<button id="show">showpic</button>
<button id="close">closepic</button>
<pre></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested it on FireFox 25+, Chrome 31+

And it works.

When I click on 'showpic' button the script will change the url to 'picurlhere.jpg' and when I click back to 'closepic' button it will return me the original page URL.

This will help us while showing images using JQuery or JavaScript methods so we can change the browser url because if the user copy the link and send it to any one it will point him to the picture url not to the site page. and that is exactly used on instgram.

but in real show you have to make this script more smarter.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by manipulating the browser history using the `history.pushState()` method on supported browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries for details.

Answer (score -1):

No need to use any script, just plain HTML. Wrap your image like this:

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/p/ReTycBy2Bj/"><img src="your-image.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: if i use ur code and click on the picture the brwoser will take me to a new page http://instagram.com/p/ReTycBy2Bj/ , but in my question I just want to change the browser address URL without moving to new file. so we need to change the address bar URL using JavaScript.